# How to maintain connection state between many Activities?

Tags: rxandroidble

According to rxandroidble, dispose() should be called in onPause() of Activity lifeCycle, then the BLE connection will be close? And
I can only connect BLE device in new Activity, and if I don't call dispose(), it will come up with BleAlreadyConnectedException(“Already connected to device with MAC address ***”) when I connect to BLE device in new Activity.

So, how can I maintain connection state between Activities?

Answer (score 3):

To keep a reference to anything longer than the lifecycle of an `Activity` one has to move the reference *outside* of the scope of this `Activity`.

On Android platform there are several ways to achieve this separation of lifecycles. By the book approach would be a [`Service`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services) which can be started by an `Activity` and stopped by a different one. Activities can communicate with the `Service` for instance by using [binding](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services) — just be sure that the `Service` is started as it may be killed if left without any bound clients (activities).

Interface of the `Service` may vary on case-by-case basis — you will have to design what will suit your needs best.

Alternative (discouraged) approach could be [the singleton pattern](https://www.journaldev.com/1377/java-singleton-design-pattern-best-practices-examples).